# Using Serilog over a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, serilog, seq-logging

I have a web application that is split into two sections, website and API.

The website sits within the DMZ so is segregated from our internal network, for this reason all data access is done via the API which is internal.

Our Seq server is internal.  Therefore anything I log in the website would need to be passed to the API first for it to then then log.

I can do this with a basic string, but struggling when attempting to serialise the structured message for it to be picked up in the API (and sent to SEQ).

***I'm looking for a way for Serilog to pass it's structured data across the wire to be stored in SEQ by the API (using Serilog or other).***

The API is also logging it's own events so the answer would need to ensure it can continue.

I have found a number of sinks that send over HTTP - but how would I receive this back into Serilog/SEQ?

Comment: The [_Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion_ sample](https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-browserhttp/tree/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion) in `nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-browerhttp` shows one possible approach. The README in that repo shows how `UseSerilogIngestion()` is called. HTH